# Any Books/Sites/Writeups on IRC bot Security?

Tags: attack-prevention

I've written a scriptable IRC Bot and I want to harden it against exploits. To that end I've already written it so that it ignores its own messages (so that, for example, even if it echoes back valid commands for itself it won't execute them) and restricted certain features to a list of "authorized nicknames" so that sensitive functions can't be invoked by just anyone. Also, the nature of the scripting language precludes any `eval`-like exploits.

With all that said, I can still think of numerous ways of exploiting my bot. Are there any writings on the subject of IRC Bot security? Even a short article from a more competent programmer than I on the topic would be useful, but Google is not cooperating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like any software you need to harden it to only allow the user what you intend to allow him. In your specific question it really relies on what language you have programmed your bot in, what types of commands you allow it and how it sanitizes the input from the user.

I am not familiar with any books directly targeting security of an IRC bot, however there should be many clear guidelines on how to program safely in the programming language of your choice.

It is also very relevant to read the [RF1459](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1459) on how your bot should behave when communicating over IRC.

---

When you initially set up your IRC bot make sure that the core functionality is in place and working properly. This is the simple stuff like:

- replying to ping with pong
- join channels

Then you need to dissect these operations and make sure that they are inherently secure. Does your bot reply to a random PING from anyone? What if I supply a buffer overflow attack against your bot with a "PING AAAA x50000"? Does it try to store it in buffer and copy it to the PONG reply? Perhaps the only source allowed to make a PING to you should be the server your connected too.

When you later make the bot to accept commands from anyone you probably want to whitelist ([positive security model](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Positive_security_model)) the commands you allow (join, kick, ban, ping, ??) and then sanitize properly the input to the bot.

The sanitation that needs to be done is very dependent on what your bot actually does. For instance:

- It posts results to a web page ([XSS filters](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet))
- It stores data in a database ([SQL filteres](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet))
- It runs commands on OS or similar interface ([command filters](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Command_injection))

When you design such a bot you have to try think of every possible way someone will try to exploit it. You have to be very careful and paranoid when creating it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as "absolutely secure software". There is software that does the things its creator (or users) want, and does not do other (presumably unpleasant) things.

So, start with people:

1. Identify users of your software (you, customers, admins, etc)
2. Identify their needs (see [Stakeholder identification](http://easyweb.easynet.co.uk/iany/consultancy/stakeholder_taxonomy/stakeholder_taxonomy.htm) by Ian Alexander)
3. Identify potential attackers - and their interests, too.

Then we can really go down to technical things and get much more sensible results - because we'll think of "how" and "why" your bot will be exploited.

P.S. If some of this information is too sensitive, there are always things like [PGP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pretty_Good_Privacy) :)